# R shiny clear global variables after shiny app ends

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to clear the defined global variables after exiting a shiny app.

What I did is to add a `onStop` in shiny `server.R`. But it doesn't work.

Thanks a lot for your help.

```
onStop(function(){
 rm(list = ls(all.names = TRUE))
})
```

Comment: The environment that that code runs in is not necessarily `.GlobalEnv`, so you'll need to specifically target it with `envir=`. ***However***, you say you want to clear your defined global variables but instead you delete **everything**. Please don't do that, it's a bad habit, and it will bite hard when you least expect it to. Likely the simplest method would be to define a character vector of the defined global variables you want to delete, then use `rm(list=thatvec)` and with the `envir=` of choice.

Comment: @r2evans, Thanks a lot for your help. It is very useful. I also want to free up memory after closing shiny. So I added `gc()` inside `onStop`. But I got the following error: Error in execCallbacks(timeoutSecs, all, loop$id) : 
  invoke_wrapped: throwing std::runtime_error. Could you help to point out the reason? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, no idea in that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run code on app stop you need to provide `onStop` as an argument to `shinyApp` (nested in the `onStart` callback function).

If you place `onStop` in the server function it will run after a session stops (e.g. closing the browser window).

Please check the following the see the difference:

```
library(shiny)

myGlobalVaribale <- "Some useful global content"

ui <- basicPage(p(myGlobalVaribale),
                actionButton("stopSession", "Stop session"),
                actionButton("stopApp", "Stop app")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  onStop(function() cat("This will run on session stop\n"))
  
  observeEvent(input$stopSession, {
    cat(sprintf("Closing session %s\n", session$token))
    session$close()
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$stopApp, {
    cat("Stopping shiny app\n")
    stopApp()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server,
         onStart = function() {
           cat("This will run on app start\n")
           onStop(function() {
             cat("This will run on app stop\n")
             print(ls(envir = .GlobalEnv))
             rm(list = c("myGlobalVaribale"), envir = .GlobalEnv)
             print(ls(envir = .GlobalEnv))
           })
         }
)
```