# Shiny App R how to execute code only upon exit instead of session end?

Tags: r, session, shiny

Is there a way to execute code only after exiting a shiny app? I have been using onStop and  onSessionEnded but these execute every time the app is refreshed.

```
onStop(function() { 
if (file.exists("www/outputPlot.png")){
  png::writePNG(array(0, dim = c(1,1,4)), "www/outputPlot.png") # clears the .png from www/ so starting app loads a blank screen
}
```

})

Comment: Please read the documentation `?onStop`. To run code on app stop you need to provide `onStop` as an argument to `shinyApp` (nested in the `onStart` callback function).
If you place `onStop` in the server function it will run after a session stops (e.g. closing the browser window).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R shiny clear global variables after shiny app ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68491861/r-shiny-clear-global-variables-after-shiny-app-ends)